# Partitioning Sentence In Python

Tags: python

I have the following string: "Boy/N meets/V girl/N ./Punc"

How can I split this string by its word and POS tag? Ideally I would like to separate the words and POS into two different lists, `sentence = [ 'Boy', 'meets', 'girl' '.' ]` and `POS = ['N', 'V', 'N', 'Punc']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the POS tags are always preceded by a `/`, you can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split each word:

```
sent = "Boy/N meets/V girl/N ./Punc"

sentence = []
pos = []

for x in sent.split():
    s, w = x.split('/')
    sentence.append(s)
    pos.append(w)

print(sentence, pos)
# ['Boy', 'meets', 'girl', '.'] ['N', 'V', 'N', 'Punc']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wow, I was writing an answer to this but this is much smarter than mine. Well done, and thanks for teaching me something too!